# How can i present/dismiss viewcontroller from bottom to top in navigationcontroller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, show-hide, presentviewcontroller

I want to show animation from bottom to top when i am pushing viewController to navigationController?Do any have idea to do it?

```
RegisterViewController *registerView = (RegisterViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RegisterViewController"];
```

**Present**

```
[self presentViewController:registerView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**Dismiss**

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Is there any way to achieve this in navigationController?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't link Storyboard

> Present ViewController with this code

**It Will Present from bottom to top**

```
UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MYUnicornViewController"]; // Change the view controller name
[self.navigationController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

> Dismiss ViewController with this code

**It Will dismiss from top to bottom**

```
[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

[image]

Comment: Ohh! I am surprised but in this case it hides navigation bar.

Comment: Why dont you not create custom design that look like navigation on that view controller

Comment: It hides that navigation bar because with this solution your are presenting modally and not pushing onto the navigation stack.

Answer (score 1):

**Objective C:**

> Present from Bottom to Top

```
RegisterViewController *registerView = (RegisterViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RegisterViewController"];

[self.navigationController presentViewController:registerView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

> Dismiss from Top to Bottom

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

**Swift:**

> Present from Bottom to Top

```
let registerView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RegisterViewController") as! RegisterViewController

self.navigationController?.present(registerView, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

> Dismiss from Top to Bottom

```
self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can present the view controller like as answered by @PinkeshGjr,
I am adding code to add navigation bar without the custom view suggested by @Pinkeshgjr.

Instead you can simply add your view controller in Navigation controller and present.

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];//Change your storyboard name
UIViewController* myCopntroller = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewController"];//Your view controller
UINavigationController* nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myCopntroller];//Added in navigation controller
[self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];//Present you viewcontroller
```